# How can I access the underlying column after defining a @ManyToOne relationship on it in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-roo, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring 3.2 with Roo 1.2.3 to build a database-backed Java application via Hibernate.  I have several bidirectional OneToMany/ManyToOne relationships among the tables in my database.  When I set up the ManyToOne side of the relationship using @JoinColumn (via "field reference" in Roo), a new field whose type is the related entity (the "one" in ManyToOne) is created.  However, once this is done, there seems to be no way to access the underlying column value on which the ManyToOne relationship is based.  This is a problem when the underlying join column contains data needed by the application (i.e. when the join column contains product stock numbers).

Is there any way to set up my entity class so that the column on which its ManyToOne relationship is based remains accessible without traversing the new join property?  How can I define an accessor method for the value of this column?

I've been looking online for an answer to this question for several days, but to no avail. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

just map the column a second time with insertable=false and updateable=false

Answer (score 0):

To make it more concrete. It's possible to do a HQL-SELCT and restrict a **ManyToOne** relationship, **without any join** in the resulting **SQL**:

Instead of using a join in

```java
session.createQuery("FROM Person person WHERE person.adress.id = 42")
```

we use can use the `adress_id`column

```java
session.createQuery("FROM Person person WHERE person.adressId = 42")
```

This works, if you specify an additional `adressId` field, which is only used as mapping info for Hibernate:

```java
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Person{
    @Id
    String id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "adress_id") 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Nullable
    public Adress adress;


    @Column(name = "adress_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String adressId;
}


@Entity
@Access(FIELD)
public class Adress{
    @Id
    String id;
}
```

The `AccessType.FIELD` is not needed (But we can leave getters/setters in example). The `FetchType.LAZY` and `@Nullable` are also optional, but make it clear when it makes sense to use it. We are able to load `Person` entities which have a specific `Address` (we know the address id). But we don't need a join because it's not needed for the WHERE-clause and not for the initial fetch (the address can be fetched lazy).